# My customized ttf font file don't work on android 2.2

Tags: android, truetype

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);      
paint.setAntiAlias(true);    

Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name)
paint.setTypeface(t);
FontMetricsInt fm = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
if (fm.bottom-fm.top <= 0)
{
    Log.v("Cocos2dxBitmap", "invalid font metrics "+fm.bottom+", "+fm.top);
    return;
}
```

This code failed on android 2.2, works on any version above, i don't test it with lower version.

I don't find any information relate to this, i guess it has something to do with my ttf file format.

Hope someone can enlighten me on this issue, thanks.

EDIT: I've changed the ttf to a famous chinese font wqy.ttf, still have the same problem.

Comment: How did it fail? Did you get an exception? Please post the logcat output.

Comment: There is no exception, but both `fm.bottom` and `fm.top` is zero.